# When fetching data from CoinMarket API getting SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, postman

I am trying to fetch data from the [coinmarketcap api](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/). It worked through Postman once yesterday, but then ever since I keep attempting to hit the api I keep getting this error:

```
GET /cryptocurrency/info?id=1 200 - - 190.846 ms
error Error: write EPROTO 4375776704:error:1408F10B:SSL 
routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```

[image: screenshot of postman call]
This also happens when I attempt to call the api through a proxy server.

```js
const requestOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  uri: "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest",
  qs: {
    start: "1",
    limit: "10",
    convert: "USD",
  },
  headers: {
    "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "my_api_key",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true,
};
```

Everything I read says to just change `https` to `http` but the api is definitely `https` and I've tried every variation just in case (including http://localhost for the proxy layer). I've also signed up for a different API account in case the key I had originally was compromised from my initial experimenting. However the new key has the same issue.

I've run out of ideas here, does anyone else know what could be wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/request/request/issues/3233